# single responsibility principle webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I am building a WebAPI service for an application and i am stuck at a cross roads, i understand the SOLID principles and wanting to implement my WebAPI services following these principles, however i have spent the last couple of days struggling with an implementation and would like some advice from the community.

The **Single Responsibility** principle states that every class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software (see [Solid Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))

I have a two ApiControllers at the moment but there will be many more, and the two currently have Get, Post and Put functionality, but each controller will also require a Search function and my question is should the search methods be moved into a separate ApiController, called SearchController for example.

For example:

I have a user controller

```
public class UserController : ApiController {
    Get - returns a User
    Post and Put - Add and update a User
}
```

and i have a patient controller along the same lines as above, should i have my search methods in each controller of should i have a SearchController, eg.

```
public class SearchController : ApiController {
    SearchUsers() - returns ICollection<User>
    SearchPatients() - returns ICollection<Patient>
}
```

I realise there is no definitive answer and would just like some advice on the best practice

Comment: "Search" is probably just a GET with a filter, right?

Answer (score 3):

If you go insane with SRP and don't find the proper level of responsibility you end up with a zillion classes doing nothing.

I view the User controller as being responsible for mediating between the User resource api and how that concept is implemented inside of the application.  In that case it makes sense to have all api operations in a single controller.

That said we follow Command/Query separation so our controllers delegate to commands or queries to do the actual work.  That way the only reason our controller should change is if we want to change the API we provide.

Comment: Still, I assume that every command/query is injected into the ApiController. This means that every action probably uses at least one, but probably none of the ones from the other actions. This results in a webapi controller that is littered with dependencies of which only a few are used. In that case I'd prefer using a single class per method and just making sure you put them in a clear folder structure that prevents stuff from becoming a mess.

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce search as an action on the respective controller and if you want to track all controllers that have a search action, put an interface on it.

```cs
public interface ISearchable
{
    IHttpActionResult Search(string q);
}

public class UsersController : ApiController, ISearchable
{
    [Route("api/Users/Search")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Search([FromUri] string q)
    {
        var userRepo = new UserRepo();

        //this search method can be as complex as needed
        //search initials, middle names, phone numbers, whatever you need.
        var results = userRepo.Search(q);

        return this.Ok(results);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
https://domain.com/api/Users/Search?q=smith
```

This keeps it very clear to your clients since they don't have to know about a specific SearchController that would basically be a bunch of RPC's. If you think about what search is, it's basically a verb that isn't a standard http verb, so we attach it to the route as an action. We are still acting upon the Users collection similar to a GET or POST against the collection. Since we don't have SEARCH as a valid HTTP method, an action is the next best thing.

In reference to SOLID. This keeps your controller as simple a controller. It's job (IMO) is to control the request and route that to logic. In this case, it took the route, mapped it to a UserRepo and executed the Search method. Searching is not the job of the controller, you have another class doing that heavy lifting. The controller simply handles what logic should be executed given the request. Even the data returned is deferred until later in the pipeline via serializers so SOLID should hold true on the controller.

Comment: Given that the Usage Url you show is actually using a query string, shouldn't the parameter attribute actually be `[QueryString]` ?

Comment: @ScottK.Fraley [FromUri] works as expected and I’ve used it in many WebApi projects. I’ve never tried [QueryString] so I’ll have to give it a shot. Thanks for pointing me to something new to try.

Comment: Well I'll be.. I always just assumed that `[FromUri]` meant that it (any given param) had to be part of the Url, e.g. `api/bla/Param1Value` and wouldn't work with query string(s). Thanks for teaching ME something I didn't know! (But of course should have tried!)